# AngularJS on Rails: angular routes or rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a project using AngularJS upon Rails. The API is written using Grape, and will be accessed by both website and mobile apps. To be clear, the website is NOT a one-page webapp. Instead, it contains some static pages like about/privacy/features, as well as pages with dynamic contents like recent posts.

For the website part, I came across two ways to choose between (take `posts#index` and `posts#show` as an example):

**The mostly AngularJS way:**

- Rails does very little about page routing
- AngularJS fetch html partials according to URL
- All templates would be placed under `assets/javascripts/angular-app/templates`
- Almost no Rails controller for website part.

**The mostly Rails way:**

- Rails serve `views/posts/show.html` and `views/posts/index.html` as usual, according to URL.
- Views/templates are static, and delegates dynamic stuffs to AngularJS controllers using `ng-xxx`.
- AngularJS controller access API, fetch json data, display it.

### The question:

What are the benefits/drawbacks for these two ways considering:

1. Logical / make sense
2. Easy to test and manage

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to use rails at all? If you have a grape api why not just consume it with an all javascript app?

Comment: @ptd The main reason is that I'm much more familiar with Rails than with javascript or any js-based web framework. Besides, Rails/slim is really making html templates a breeze, although I don't know if that's also true in js world.